# qlpreviewcontroller navigation bar - How to Change pageCount to String

Tags: ios, swift, qlpreviewcontroller

[image]

QLPreviewController navigationBar Title showing current page number like 2 of 6 but I want to change this title to any String like current file name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
        let lblNavTitle = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 60, y: 10, width: view.frame.size.width-110, height: 20))
        lblNavTitle?.textAlignment = .center
        lblNavTitle?.lineBreakMode = .byTruncatingMiddle
        lblNavTitle?.text = "File Name"
        navigationItem.titleView = lblNavTitle
```

OR

Simply set title property like

```
self.title = "File Name"
```

May be it will work for you